# In GAE/P, how often are module-level statements executed?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Consider a Python module in Google App Engine that looks like this:

```
a = some_function()

def some_function():
   return 1
```

In a deployed App Engine app, how frequently is `some_function()` executed?

For example, is it:

1. Each time an instance is created?
2. Each time a request is received that causes the Python module to be imported?
3. Something else?

I'm hoping it is 1 so that I use that to make my app more efficient.